# How to read the contents in svc.log

Tags: svchost

Svchost.exe is creating the log file as svc.log in the path "c:\windows\system32\logfiles\sum". How to read them and see the content inside the log files. I tried with notepad, notepad++ (used different encoding) and Microsoft service trace viewer, nothing helped.

I am seeing junk characters only. What is the file format of this log file and which tool I can use to open and read them.